# Using scripts to create forms in non-root folders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to write a script to convert spreadsheet column headers to questions in a form.  I'd like to be able to run this script in the folders where the spreadsheets reside and have it create the form in the same folder.  Problem is, no matter where I place the script, the form gets created in the root folder.  I didn't find any help in the Form and FormApp documentation.  I'm certain it's just a simple mod to the function call, but...

```
function createForm()
{
  // Create a new form, then add a checkbox question, a multiple choice question,
// a page break, then a date question and a grid of questions.
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
var form = FormApp.create('Form Name');
var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
item.setTitle('This is a bunch of gibberish!!!!!!!!!!!!');
item.setChoices([
        item.createChoice('Relish')
    ]);
Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty solution would be the following:

```
function createForm(){
//get the form file through id of the form you just made
var form     = FormApp.create('tempForm'),
    id       = form.getId(),
    formFile =  DriveApp.getFileById(id);
//get the id of the folder you want to move the form to
var folderId   = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderID');
//delete the temporary form
formFile.setTrashed(true);
//copy the temp form (still active) to the destination folder, open it.
var newId    = formFile.makeCopy(folder).setName('myCopiedForm').getId(),
    form     = FormApp.openById(newId);
}
```

It's dirty but it works. If there is a better solution, please let me know.